# How to remove message when I use attach function in r

Tags: r

```
 x=runif(5,0,1)
 y=rbinom(5,1,0.1)
 z=cbind.data.frame(x,y)
 z
##           x y
##1 0.16082314 0
##2 0.16499635 0
##3 0.06745912 0
##4 0.15656984 1
##5 0.61250111 1
 attach(z)
##The following objects are masked _by_ .GlobalEnv:

 ##   x, y
```

How to remove this message that give me when I use `attach(z)`, I do not want to give me any thing .

Comment: It is better not to use `attach`

Comment: `suppressMessages(attach(z))` would suppress the message.  But I agree with akrun regarding the use of `attach()`.  You will also see this message on some calls to `library()` as well though, so good to know how to suppress it.

Comment: thanks to all I appreciate

Comment: by the way, you can just write `z = data.frame(x = runif(5), y = rbinom(5, 1, .1))`

Comment: @akrun , but I need it . can you tell me another function instead of `attach `

Comment: @adam - `$`, as in `z$x` to access the `x` column in `z`.  You could also use `with()`, as in `with(z, x)`

Answer (score 0):

O agree with @richard that the best (and preferable) alternatives are `with()` or `within()`, depending on what you need to do with objects inside of these functions.